# casting dataframe to_numpy array removes decimal number but leaves the decimal period

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Hello people of the web,

I am trying to transform a dataframe's column into a numpy array, yet I find myself having a weird issue I couldn't verbalise good enough in order to find any information to handle it.

The original dataframe:
[image]

The column 'height' is the one i'm trying to transform (the rightest column in the df) using to_numpy function, in the following way:

[image]

gives me the following result:
[image]

as you can notice in the 3rd image, to_numpy() has erased the rightest digit (the 0) from the heights while leaving the decimal period in place..

I have tried using astype(float) **without success**, in the following ways:

```
data.iloc[:, size_df].astype(float).to_numpy()
data.iloc[:, size_df].to_numpy().astype(float)
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: You could set the type to `int`, e.g. `.to_numpy(dtype=int)`.

Comment: Those are the same numbers, just different styles of display.  For a dataframe use `df.dtypes`, for an array `arr.dtype` to see what the respective dtypes are.

Answer (score 0):

So, as @hpaulj mentioned, it's just a representation of the same number. Following his advice, I printed the datatype, and I could see that it is still considered as a float:

```
print(data.iloc[:, size_df].to_numpy().dtype) // prints 'float64'
```

In order to get rid of the decimal point, I could cast, as @sj95126 suggested, to integer, by using
`.to_numpy(dtype=int)`